# How can I record the sound output from programs in windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, audio, recording

I would like to record the sound output from specific programs in windows 7. On osx I'm aware of programs called audiohijack and soundflower. I'd like to find something similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This thread](http://forum.audacityteam.org/viewtopic.php?f=36&t=4826) in Audacity's forum shows many ways of doing it, but I am using their last suggestion: It's [Freecorder](http://www.freecorder.com/freecorder3), a browser plugin, that records the Windows audio output.

Comment: Freecorder also come with several adware that are installed in your browser.

Comment: right... DO NOT INSTALL THIS CRAP. Freecorder installs about 5 other different things, replaces your chrome toolbar pin with theirs and changes your search engine.

Answer (score 9):

I love and swear by [audacity](http://audacity.sourceforge.net/).  I use it all the time for recording sound output.  It should work for you, too.

Comment: Also, it doesn't list Windows 7 as compatible but I use it in Windows 7 all the time without any problems.

Comment: That's what version 1.3.12 (Beta) is for, Win7 compatibility.

Comment: This doesn't allow to select the program, and it doesn't work if your device doesn't have a "stereo mix" input.

Answer (score 5):

What you want is Total Recorder by [High Criteria](http://www.highcriteria.com/). I've been using it for years and have been very happy with it. Good support as well. I should also mention that in addition to being run interactively (in a window), it can be launched via the command line as well. I use it to record some weekly radio shows that I'm rarely home for and use the Task Scheduler to launch it, specifying the length of recording, etc. A very handy feature.

Supports XP, Vista, and Windows 7. Their upgrade policy is very liberal.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a virtual audio driver - I'm using [this one here](http://vb-audio.pagesperso-orange.fr/Cable/index.htm) which is donationware. It creates new input and output devices.

You set the output to this device in your audio settings (the speaker in the system tray), you start recording from this virtual device (people on this thread mentioned audacity, which is a great tool, but you can really use any tool, even the built-in Sound Recorder), then start playback.

Comment: Setting the output device to "CABLE Input" has the side effect of making you unable to hear sound output from your actual speakers. But you can fix this by also downloading Audio Density Demo from [that site](http://vb-audio.pagesperso-orange.fr/Cable/index.htm) and opening it, then selecting an output device from the Options menu. (This fix is suggested in [the VB-Cable manual](http://vb-audio.pagesperso-orange.fr/Cable/VBCABLE_CaseStudy_XP.pdf).)

Answer (score 1):

On Vista and Windows 7 you don't need any additional software. You can simply set your Sound Recording settings to Stereo Mix (disable all other recording devices and set Stereo Mix as default) and record using the Sound Recorder program - anything destined for the speakers will be recorded. The name of the recording device might differ depending on the sound driver.

[image: Stereo Mix]

[image: Sound Recorder]

Also, many manufacturers do not provide drivers that allow Stereo Mix (see this [related post](https://superuser.com/questions/299082/whats-the-reason-behind-stereo-mix-becoming-a-missing-option) and [this thread](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-pictures/i-cant-find-stereo-mix-in-windows-7-it-was-in/1140ff33-fd6c-4b4e-80ab-4f94ffe77309?auth=1) on the Microsoft support forum).

Answer (score 0):

Additionally, if you are really looking for encoding options. VLC. And you don't have to 'install' anything because it comes as a portable zipped exe too.

Menu: Media > Convert / Save
[image]

Tab: Capture Device
Set the Audio device name to "What you hear"
[image]

Click convert/save
Set your format.

[image]

You're free to play with the other options at your leisure, but that will get you going!