# Recording both internal audio and microphone via PulseAudio

Tags: linux, audio-recording, pulse-audio

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are some specific audio / sound card / driver setups that still allow you to “record what you hear”?](https://superuser.com/questions/385171/what-are-some-specific-audio-sound-card-driver-setups-that-still-allow-you-t)

I'm looking to get a sane audio recording set up that allows me to record a monitor of internal audio, and mix in line input or microphone, perhaps allowing me some sort of control about how the mix happens.

I've found alsa unable to handle it, although I might be wrong. Folks have pointed me at PulseAudio, and I've managed a somewhat acceptable solution via module-loopback. Some people have mentioned Jack, but I'm not familiar with it.

Bar buying a multi channel card and a hardware mixer, what are my options?

Comment: But a compact 5 or 6 channel hardware mixer (connected to microphone, line-out & line-in) costs about as much as a meal for two in a simple restaurant and gives you a lot of control.

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick — In the states, maybe. Where I live, I can eat for two months for the price of one.

Comment: Can you really eat out for two months in Spain on [EUR 35](http://www.thomann.de/gb/behringer_xenyx_502.htm?gclid=CMaj1pPpwbMCFePHtAodNEMAnA)?

Comment: Considering I have to pay EUR 20 for shipping, plus import tax once it arrives here, I can probably eat one whole month, yes.

Comment: I have decided I shall retire to Spain :-)