# Recording microphone and computer audio at the same time in Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, audio, audio-recording

How can I make my computer record computer audio and microphone audio at the same time (stereomix or otherwise).

I've tried to set up defaults several ways and none of them seem to work. I'm using a 'just gets by' headset so there aren't any special options for it. Also another worthy thing to note is that under my computer speakers, there is no separate options for microphone, speaker, etc output volume. I doubt it matters, but I have HP Beats Audio on my laptop.

Every tutorial I've tried uses options I don't have, or just doesn't work in general. Maybe I'm just missing something. Anyways, thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: What are you trying to record exactly?

Comment: @Ramhound Screen recording video games. As of now, Wildstar. Currently it will record both if I have the microphone set as default and default communication, however, there is a bunch of fuzz that starts if I don't talk. But I believe there is a way to do it through stereomix, and I think it would record better if I do it that way.

Comment: Also another thing to add, through that method, the computer audio comes through really quiet and low quality.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Voicemeeter is typically made to allow that ! It is a virtual audio device Mixer able to mix/route several audio sources (for example your MIC and computer sound) to different audio points (for example to your speaker and to Audacity or whatever audio recorder applications)! More info and complete documentation on [www.voicemeeter.com](http://www.voicemeeter.com) (get latest version on their facebook/G+ pages).
Many tutorial on youtube...

[image: Voicemeeter Connection Diagram]

Comment: Thank you, this works so well. I set it up in a matter of 10 minutes, and now I just need to tweak the volumes a little bit. This takes like 75% of the stress out of recording...

Answer (score 2):

You can record your System audio + microphone on Win 8 or 10 using Audacity.

Steps:
STEP 1: Right Click on Speaker/Volume icon on your task bar then click "Open Sound Settings".

Step 2: On the left side of the newly open window you'll find Related Settings. Click on  "Sound Control Panel"

Step 3: Now Click on Recording Tab ---> Right click on your Microphone icon then clik on "Properties"

Step 4: Goto Listen Tab then Tick/Check the box that says "listen to this device"

STEP 5: Open Audacity then Select WASAPI (Windows Audio Session API) as your audio HOST.
Select Your default playback Device (Headphones or Speakers)  as Recording Device.

STEP 6: Press"Record" and now you should be able to capture both your microphone and system audio.

Here is a short YouTube Video version of what I wrote above:
[How To Record Speakers & Microphone at the  same time in Audacity](https://youtu.be/JyuQ254Yhio)

Comment: This works, but also leads to your microphone playing on your headphones the entire time, which is not a great experience

Answer (score -2):

It's very big and serious question.

*Firstly:*
You need specialized software like [Adobe Audition](http://www.adobe.com/products/audition.html), [Steinberg Cubase](http://www.steinberg.net/en/products/cubase/start.html) and etc.

*Secondly:* 
If you wand make quality product you also need specialized hardware. For example external sound devices (aka [USB sound cards](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00JE1SOFY)) and/or [mixing console](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sound_mixer).

It all depends on what exactly you need and what you specifically want to record: sound, voice, music (even depends on the genre of music).