# How do you direct audio output to input via software?

Tags: windows-7, audio

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What's the reason behind “Stereo Mix” becoming a missing option?](https://superuser.com/questions/299082/whats-the-reason-behind-stereo-mix-becoming-a-missing-option)

On Windows XP, one could achieve that by selecting "What you hear" as input channel in the sound mixer panel. They apparently removed this feature in Windows 7. Do you know how to redirect audio output to the input channel in Windows 7?

Answer (score 0):

h
I also had this problem - I used "Stereo mix" as record sound input for Audacity and missed it in Win7. However, [there is a solution](http://wiki.audacityteam.org/index.php?title=Windows_Vista_OS#Using_the_Control_Panel_to_select.2Fenable_recording_devices), how to get Stereo Mix working under Win7 - according to Audacity wiki it is for Vista, but should be also usable for Win7. In my case it worked. :-)